# Intersection line and plane - vector to equation to matrix

Tags: vectors

I need to find the coordinates of the intersection of the following plane and line through (0,0,0):

[image]

Translation: "en" means "and"

I do this by writing out the equations, claiming them to be equal [image]

and thus creating a matrix to solve for $\lambda, \mu, \sigma $:

[image]

So $\lambda=3, \mu=0, \sigma=4$, but this isn't the answer as the equations are NOT equal for those values. I really do not see where I go wrong though...

I expected not to find any solution, as the line and the plane are parallel. Is the fact that the solution I find is not a real answer to the problem an indication of this? I do not think so. I think there is a mistake in rewriting the equations to the matrix, but I really do not see what goes wrong.

This all should be very easy :( But even after 1 hour I do not see my mistake. I would really appreciate some input on my line of thought.

Comment: What system did you solve to get $\textbf{x}$?

Comment: The I rewrote the systems of equations to put all the terms with greek letters on the left (matrix A) and the numbers to the right (vector b). 
**A** times **x** should be **b**. So I sweeped matrix A | b. 
The first column of A is lambda, the second mu and the third sigma.

Comment: If $\textbf{b}$ is a column vector with entries $\lambda,\mu,$ and $\sigma$ in that order then $A\textbf{b}=\textbf{0}$ will give you a solution for $\textbf{b}$ which will give you $\textbf{x}$.

Comment: Do you see the images in the post? I used Matrix A and solution matrix b (not zero) to find x, thus in my system I have **Ax** = **b**. But the x which I find this way (row manipulation) is not an answer 

And there should be NO ANSWER POSSIBLE as the line and plane are parallel

Answer (score 1):

The system of equations you're trying to express as a matrix operation is:

$\sigma\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-2\\ 
-4\\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3\\
0\\ 
-2\\
\end{array}
\right)+\lambda\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\ 
1\\
\end{array}
\right)+\mu\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
-1\\ 
-3\\
\end{array}
\right)$

Hence, $
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & -1 \\
  1 & -1 & 2 \\
  1 & -3 & 4
 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda \\ 
\mu \\
\sigma
 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
  -3 \\ 
0 \\
2
 \end{pmatrix}$

Row reducing (what you were referring to as sweeping, I believe) will give you solutions for $\lambda, \mu,$ and $\sigma$. In order to find $\textbf{x}$, we use the fact that

$\sigma\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\ 
-2 \\
-4
 \end{pmatrix}=\textbf{x}$

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is what I did. But the solutions I find this way ($\lambda=3, \mu=0, \sigma=4$) are not right, for they do not fit. 
I substracted row 1 (R1) from R2 and R3. Then I added 3*R3 to R2 and this way I got $\sigma=-1, \mu=0, \lambda=-2$. Using the software Maple to solve it gave the answers in the first post though. **Neither are actual answers to the original system.** So something goes wrong during the calculation of these systems. It shouldn't, but it does... And I don't see where and it really bugs me.

Comment: Row reducing will yield that $0=1$, in the equation that would normally yield $\sigma$; that is, that there is no solution. I noticed that there is a mistake in your matrix, maybe that accounts for it: check the third row, second column entry.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I was looking for. You just made my day :D

Comment: No problem, glad to help.